# How can I create two different if clauses on the same expression area on Report Builder?

Tags: expression, report-builder2.0

How can i create two different if clauses on the same expression area on Report Builder?

First one:

```
=IIf( Fields!productidname.Value="" , Fields!productdescription.Value, Fields!productidname.Value);
```

Second one:

```
=Iff(Fields!tler.Value="", " ","-- (" & Fields!tler.Value & " ) ")
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might be what you are looking for;

```
=
IIf(Fields!productidname.Value="" , Fields!productdescription.Value, Fields!productidname.Value)
&
Iff(Fields!tler.Value="", " ","-- (" & Fields!tler.Value & " ) ")
```